# Appcelerator Titanium module TiJSPDF

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, jspdf

I would like to use this module on my Titanium project : https://github.com/AppWerft/TiJSPDF

To install, I have just copied the folder 'modules' in my project and I have added it in tiapp.xml.

When I try to use it :

```
require('ti.jspdf');
var doc = new jsPDF();
```

I get the following error :

```
- Message: Uncaught ReferenceError: jsPDF is not defined
```

I think I don't use this module correctly. Can you help me, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a javascript module and not a compiled module, put it in the app/lib folder of your alloy project. See the documentation on Javascript modules here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/CommonJS_Modules_in_Titanium-section-src-29004791_CommonJSModulesinTitanium-JavaScriptModules

Comment: Ok, so, in my controller, how can I import this module ? I tried to put it in the app/lib folder of my alloy project and `var PDF = new (require('../lib/ti.jpdf'))();` in my controller. But I get this error : `Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: ../lib/ti.jpdf`

Comment: if it is in the lib folder, then just require('ti.jspdf'); just like you had originally.